# Ubuntu unable to upgrade to 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 19.10 and am trying to upgrade to 20.04.1. I have followed all kinds of tutorials, but in the end I am always facing the same problem. When I run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The log is:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
```

If I run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

The log is:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

I also tried upgrading from Software Updater, and when I try to, the window just disappears. By the way, I have 1GB free memory, I don't know if this could be the problem.

P.S: The output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```